# Changing background of cell in tableview behaves not as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have 2 tableviews: vertical tableview displaying content and horizontal for page navigation. I use NSMutableSet for keeping viewed pages numbers.

When changing cell/textview backgorund color or any attribute (for displaying that page was visited) excepting textview's text every seventh cell/textview also accepts changes.

Any ideas what could I do to make them behave as I want?

Comment: This is very unclear. Try rewording the question...

Comment: Prima facie this looks like table view cell reuse issue. But difficult to suggest any solution due to lack of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When changing cell/textview backgorund color or any other attribute every
>   seventh cell/textview also accepts changes.

The Problem is due to re-usability of your `UITableViewCell`. Modify your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this...

**Sample Code :**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"MyCellType";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        /* You should Create your Cell Here */
    }
    // And Configure your Cell Here...
}
```